# Extract data whose pattern spans across lines in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I have a multi-line strings that looks like:

```
value1: [

    2018
  ],
value2: [              2019
     ],
```

how would I grab just the number for value1 between the two square brackets when there could be a variable number of whitespace and newlines surrounding the number?  Is there a easy regex, or should I strip out all the whitespace and then search?

Comment: Is this JSON data?

Comment: It's not JSON; it requires quoted strings for keys.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as some 'pseudo-json'. Exists the [JSON::Relaxed](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Relaxed) module, which could parse such data. From the docs,

> Strings can be quoted with either single or double quotes. Space-less
>   strings are also parsed as strings.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use JSON::Relaxed 'from_rjson';

my $rstr = do { local $/; <DATA> };       # load the json-like data
my $d = from_rjson( '{' . $rstr . '}' );  # make a hash and parse

say $d->{value2}->[0];  # 2019

__DATA__
value1: [

    2018
  ],
value2: [              2019
     ],
```

Of course, the sample data is very small, maybe the full set would not be parseable with the above module.

Answer (score -3):

https://regex101.com/r/n2VLSO/2

`/^value\d+[:\w ]*\[\s*?(\d+)\s*?\]/gm`

---

I'm not sure why this has garnered so many negative votes without a comment.  This is simple and the answer does not need to be major or super explanatory.  If you don't think it works, run it yourself (https://ideone.com/OPV8no):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Example of string setup
my $str = qq{
value1: [

    2018
  ],
value2: [              2019
     ], 
};

# Iterate over string and store desired values
my $search_values = [1,2];
my $matches = {};
foreach my $number (@$search_values){
  if ($str =~ m/^value${number}[:\w ]*\[\s*?(\d+)\s*?\]/gm){
    $matches->{qq{value$number}} = $1;
  }
}

# Example of result
use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper($matches);
```

So, `$matches->{'value1'}` would yield `2018`